# Reading and storing values - Android

Tags: android

I develop app and I need to store and read ( read every 60 seconds, store rare ) data. What is the most easy way to achieve this? Does anybody have code sample to help me 
 ?

Comment: Reading what where to what purpose? You need to clarify your question.

Comment: I need to store medicine information (name, dosage ) and I need to store date when patient need to drink ( and how often for example on six hours) and to alert him with service in background. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is very vague, this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) should point you in the right direction.

Android has several methods of persisting data, namely using SQLite, internal storage, external storage, or network storage. There are others, but these are the big ones.

It's hard to know what you're trying to do, but I would start by looking into SQLite. If you're unfamiliar with it, you should check out this very simple [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html). It will teach you the basics of storing and reading data from an SQLite DB.

Again, if you could be more specific, I might be able to give you more specific advice, but I think this should put you in the right direction.

Comment: More specific, I insert in my app perscriptions, dosage, start time, end time and time interval when patient need to drink that medicine. I need to store somewhere somehow that data and to read then often and to alert patient to not forget to drink medicine (there may be couple medicine at different time ).

Comment: Then certainly what you want is SQLite. Check out the links I posted above. Also, here's a link to the SQLite Android API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html